# How to publish features and bundles to existing p2 repository with category?

Tags: tycho

I could install features and bundles to locally existing repository:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-p2-extras-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>publish-features-and-bundles</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <append>true</append>
                <sourceLocation>${project.build.directory}/repository</sourceLocation>
                <metadataRepositoryLocation>existingRepo</metadataRepositoryLocation>
                <artifactRepositoryLocation>existingRepo</artifactRepositoryLocation>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It worked well.
However, installed features are not categorized in destination repository.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Directly calling the category publisher on an existing p2 repository is currently not possible. There is a [feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=347303) for this, so if you want this feature vote for it and/or [contribute a patch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Contributor_Guide).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a Tycho build which

- References you published repository as layout=p2 repository in the POM, and
- Includes a module with packaging eclipse-repository and a category.xml file with your categories.

For this build, you can put all configuration into one pom.xml; you don't even need to set up a parent POM. However this build needs to be triggered separately from the build that calls the publish-features-and-bundles goal.